# RSS giving me unclosed tag link, couldn't get the innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm doing a study using a RSS, but the Web Site gives me a RSS with an unclosed tag  then I couldn't get the innerHTML of this tag.

I don't know how to resolve the problem with jquery and make the tag closed or a possible solution like this.

Here is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" content="xml">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="api/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="someElement" visibility="hidden"></p>
<p id="anotherElement"></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
        x.open("GET", "http://www.lemonde.fr/rss/une.xml", true);
        x.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200)
        {
            var doc = x.responseXML;
            var string = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(doc); 
            $("#someElement").append(string);

            alert("test");


            var tag = document.getElementsByTagName("item");

            for(var i = 0, max = tag.length; i < max; i++){

                var htmli = tag[i];
                //alert(htmli.innerHTML); 
               //uncomment the alert to see the xml got from the rss 
                var title = htmli.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML;
                var link = htmli.getElementsByTagName("link")[0].innerHTML;
                var description = htmli.getElementsByTagName("description")[0].innerHTML;
                var toAdd = "<ul><li> title : " +title+"</li><li> link : "+ link +" </li><li> description :"+description+" </li></ul>";

                $("#anotherElement").append(toAdd);
            }
        }
    };
    x.send(null);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any solution to this?

I have jquery in a folder named api.

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: I think `var tag = document.getElementsByTagName("item");` should be `var tag = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");`.

Answer (score 0):

(I notice that while you include jQuery in a script tag, you're not actually using it in your code. It's much better practice to use jQuery's functionality to manage AJAX requests and serialization, if you're going to use it at all, as they cover many more situations and browser versions. I'd also recommend [retrieving jQuery from a CDN](https://code.jquery.com) rather than hosting it yourself. jQuery has had the ability to parse XML natively since 1.5. The following was written using 1.12.)

I ran into the same issue with unclosed  tags in an RSS feed and came up with a terrible solution to it. I have not tested this cross-browser and would not recommend incorporating it into production code, but it worked to solve a one-time problem for me.

The idea is to take the raw output of the RSS item's text, cram it into the jQuery HTML parser, and then manually inspect its output until we get to an item that it thinks might have been an HTML <link> tag. Because we know the RSS link tag isn't closed, the next thing it encounters should be parsed as an HTML Text object, which we can extract for our permalink URL.

Here's how I would rewrite your script to take better advantage of jQuery and incorporate my hack. (I'm assuming you have set up CORS or something else so that you can actually retrieve the feed from lemonde.fr cross-domain.)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" content="xml">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <p id="someElement" visibility="hidden"></p>
  <p id="anotherElement"></p>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($, window, document) {

      function fetchFeed(url) {
        // use jQuery to handle AJAX
        $.get(url, function(data) {
          // parse XML result with jQuery
          var $XML = $(data);
          $XML.find("item").each(function() {
            // ensure that we have a jQuery-wrapped _this_ object and 
            // create a new object with the properties we want
            var $this = $(this),
              item = {
                title: $this.find("title").text(),
                description: $this.find("description").text(),
                link: ""
              };
            // since the XML parser will treat the unclosed <link> as valid,
            // we instead send the raw output to the HTML parser and tell it do to its best
            var $redigested = $($this.html());
            // jQuery should produce an array of HTML DOM objects
            for (var i = 0; i < $redigested.length; i++) {
              // if we found an HTMLLinkElement--a <link> tag--followed by a Text element, that's our URL
              if ($redigested[i] instanceof HTMLLinkElement && $redigested.length >= i + 1 && $redigested[i + 1] instanceof Text) {
                item.link = $redigested[i + 1].data;
                break;
              }
            }
            console.log("link: " + item.link);
            var toAdd = "<ul><li> title: " + item.title + "</li><li> link: " + item.link + " </li><li> description: " + item.description + " </li></ul>";
            $("#anotherElement").append(toAdd);
          });
        });
      }

      $(function() {
        // call the fetch function on DOM ready
        fetchFeed("http://www.lemonde.fr/rss/une.xml");
      });

    })(jQuery, window, document);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```